# Polish letters on black screen after starting rebooting

Tags: 18.04, lenovo

I'm new to Ubuntu, currently using 18.04.2 LTS. When I reboot or turn off computer, there is a long array of polish letters displayed on black screen ('ś', 'ć' etc.) for a while. Is there any way to turn this off or maybe this is something I should worry about? Model of laptop is Lenovo Ideapad 330-15.

Comment: Can You provide a screenshot of it ?

Comment: As I mentioned, there is nothing except letters (no logs). Also, this screen appears for a a very short period of time, so I'm not able to take a photo of it.